# Global Entry with Foreign Address in Foreign Language

Tags: global-entry

I recently moved abroad and I'd like to sign up for Global Entry now that I'm back in the US for a few months. Problem is, all of my documentation attesting to my current foreign address is in a foreign language. How can I present evidence of my residence?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Is your residence evidence (say, a drivers license or house rental agreement) in Latin letters? Why do you think you can't enter a non-US address?

Comment: I am a dual American Israeli citizen. My housing documents are all in Hebrew and though I can write the address in Latin letters, I don't have any documentation with those letters.

Comment: Address in not a proof of residence (and residence is a broad term, with different meaning in different countries). If the document show that you have a residence in Israel, it should be enough. If you google (in google map) your transliterated address, do you find your street? Note: immigration uses expert on specific countries (consular officers who lived and worked in such country for some time) to check validity of documents.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, For Global Entry purposes "residency" does indeed mean "current residential address". See, e.g., [the "What should I bring to the interview?" question in the "Appointments" section of the FAQ](https://ttp.dhs.gov/faq). If I were the in the OP's position I might get one of the address documents translated (using that one to point out the matching Hebrew address in the other documents) since it is CBP officers rather than consular staff that needs to be made happy.

Comment: There are various questions here about certified or official translations of documents; it's quite common for visas.